# Como mudar a pasta do site no Apache2?

Tags: linux, apache, lamp

Preciso de ajuda na configuração do LAMP. Tudo está funcionando perfeitamente. As coisas que eu gostaria de mudar são meros caprichos, mas mesmo assim acho interessante.

Gostaria de mudar o diretório raiz. No caso está em: `/var/www/html`, eu gostaria de um diretório nos documentos, por exemplo.

Também gostaria de remover a tela inicial:

[image: Página padrão do Apache2 no Ubuntu]

Eu preciso que no lugar dessa tela inicial do *localhost*, aparecesse a listagem de pasta e arquivos. Nada mais. Exemplo:

[image: Listagem de pastas Apache]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Para começar eu gostaria de mudar o destido da pasta, no caso ela está em: /var/www/html, eu gostaria de colocar um diretorio nos documentos por exemplo

1) Abra o arquivo de configuração do *Apache*:

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

2) Procure a configuração `DocumentRoot` e altere para o diretório que você quer:

Por padrão, deve estar assim: `DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"`

3) Procure a configuração do diretório e altere o caminho também:

```
<Directory "/var/www/public_html">
...
</Directory>
```

> Eu preciso que no lugar dessa tela inicial do localhost, aparecesse um index simples com as pastas dos meus projetos e nada mais.

4) Na configuração do diretório, procure a linha `Options` e certifique-se de que tenha `Indexes`:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

5) No arquivo `.htaccess` não pode haver a opção `-Indexes`, ou irá sobrescrever a diretiva no passo "4)".

6) Quando você acessa os diretórios do *Apache*, automaticamente ele busca alguns arquivos padrões a fim de exibir para o usuário. Então, você deve "tirar" estes arquivos do diretório raiz já que quer listar o conteúdo da pasta. Normalmente são estes os arquivos:

```
index.php index2.php default.php index.html index.htm
```

Você pode configurar isto no mesmo arquivo do *Apache* que alteramos anteriormente. Basta procurar a configuração:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index2.php default.php index.html index.htm
</IfModule>
```

Não recomendo mudar isso, mas se assim quiser, está aí!